# How can I define the following objective function in cvxpy?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

In cvxpy, I have variables defined as `w=Variable(10,4)`. My objective function is the sum of the dot products of each column. In Matlab it would be

```
(w(:,1)'*w(:,1) + w(:,2)'*w(:,2) + w(:,3)'*w(:,3) + w(:,4)'*w(:,4))
```

Can anyone please help how to do it in cvxpy?

Answer (score 1):

Your objective function is the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of the [Gram matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramMatrix.html), i.e., the squared [Frobenius norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html). Try:

```
objective = Minimize( norm(W,"fro") )
```